# R - Dynamic header using Sys.Date()

Tags: r

I have a data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(data = rexp(200, rate = 10), nrow = 10, ncol = 20))
```

Now I would really like to rename the headers using today's date and `Sys.Date() + ncol(df)` forward. So, my data-frame would look like this

```
2014-12-12   2014-12-13    2014-12-14   ..... 
values         values        values     .....
```

What I've tried

```
colnames(df) <- c(seq.Date(from = Sys.Date(), 
                to = Sys.Date() + ncol(df), by = "days"))
```

And

```
colnames(df) <- gsub(pattern = " ", x = c(seq.Date(from = Sys.Date(), 
                to = Sys.Date() + ncol(df), by = "days")), replacement = ",")
```

I guess it is very simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. And if I just write something a bit more static, like

```
colnames(df)[1] <- Sys.Date()
colnames(df)[2] <- Sys.Date() + 1
```

I just get the numeric presentation of the data, and not the date as in "%Y-%m%-%d".

Comment: What does `names(df) <- seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + (ncol(df) - 1), by = "days")` gives you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names(df) <- as.character(Sys.Date() + seq_along(df) - 1)
```